# Which is the best practice? Compose n items rows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

Ok, my question is: how should I do this? I wrote this and it works but I know it can be improved.

```
<% 
  index = 0 
  @lessons.each do |lesson| 
    index += 1
    if index % 4 == 1 %><div class="row"><% end %>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <%= image_tag lesson.image || '/assets/images/lessons-list-thumb-placeholder.png', class: "img-responsive" %>
        <h3><%= lesson.title %></h3>
        <p><%= lesson.difficulty %></p>
        <p><%= l(lesson.date, format: :medium) %> <%= l(lesson.time, format: :standard) %></p>
        <p><%= lesson.teacher %></p>
      </div><%
    if index % 4 == 0 or @lessons.count == index %></div><% end %>
<% end %>
```

Obviously this is in a view. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about [each_slice](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice)?

```
<% @lessons.each_slice(4) do |lesson_slice| %>
    <div class="row">
        <% lesson_slice.each do |lesson| %>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                ....
            </div>
        <% end %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use each with index

```
@lessons.each_with_index do |lesson , index|

  if condition 
  end

end
```

Comment: Mmmm,I can't figure out how this can be better. Can you complete the snippet?

Comment: I think answer given by markus is better way then me.

Comment: Ok :) I give him best answer. Thank you too.